# Processing all existing data of a single collection in Cloud Firestore using Firestore Triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase RTDB when adding a `child_added` listener, it gets called for every child that already exists, which is handy if you want to migrate data out of Firebase or do some schema migration. I can't find find evidence you can do the same using Firestore triggers. What's the recommended way to process all existing documents and any new documents in a Firestore collection?

I can think of two ways:

1. Try out whether attaching a Firestore trigger works, so you can do a live migration on some data.
2. Create some manually triggered Cloud Function that iterates over a collection and invokes another function for each collection.

If this question is too general, we have one collection that is structured in some way and needs to be written to PostgreSQL in a differently structured way at some point.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In general, I want to know how to process all (potentially many) documents in a single collection. Reasons to do so might be transferring data to a different database, denormalizing existing data to make it easier to query, or for example adding a new field based on some existing one(s) in all existing documents.

Comment: *child_added* has nothing to do with migrating data so that's a bit unclear. That function notifies the app with an event when new data is added to a node so you can take action; for example a new user is added, to which the app is notified, so the UI can display the new user. Firestore has a very similar function [addSnapshotListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) to which you can use .added, .modified and .removed to determine what happened with the data. It allows you to iterate over all documents as well.

Comment: Using `child_added` in RTDB, I could iterate over all existing and new objects. But yes, that's only client-side and not in a Function. I was wondering whether there was something like that, but for a Cloud Function and Firstore. The link to `addSnapshotListener` does not mention the listener also getting the existing documents.

Comment: See the Firestore Documentation [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) which says **Important: The first query snapshot contains added events for all existing documents that match the query**. You can definitely iterate over documents using Cloud functions as well but what are you wanting to do with each document? Do you want to export it or something along those lines? You don't need a cloud function for that - just the addSnapshotListener to get the nodes, convert them to whatever and save to disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side or some node process you can set a observer for the collection and also check what type of changes did happen on it. Here is an example:

```js
const observer = db.collection('cities')
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        console.log('New city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === 'modified') {
        console.log('Modified city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === 'removed') {
        console.log('Removed city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
    });
  });
```

The first query snapshot contains added events for all existing documents that match the query.

With using Firebase cloud functions you can use `onWrite` to be notice about every change in the collection:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('my-collection/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

And if you would like to get only elements that are added you can use the `onCreated` trigger:

```js
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = snap.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const name = newValue.name;

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

Using the Firebase cloud functions you get noticed only in real time. Everything that is already in the collection would not appear on the `onCreate` and in `onWrite` only if it gets changed or deleted.

Comment: This seems to be code ran from the client or admin SDK, right? This mean I'd have to spin up some process that does that. Is there no way I can do it with a Cloud Function that executes it more efficiently? Also, does this load all documents of the collection at once? Since there could be a lot of existing documents, wouldn't that overload the Cloud Function or Node.js process?

Comment: Sorry. I tought you where searching something on the client side. I updated the answer and added how you can do it using firebase cloud functions.

Comment: The problem with this solution it doesn't get the existing documents, which is something needed if I for example want to add a field to all existing documents AND the ones being added while the migration is running.

Comment: In the first comment you wrote that you don't want to get all documents because it would overload the Cloud Function or Node.js process? Could you pls explain a little bit more how you want to run your migration and what the use case is.

Comment: My worry is that if I receive all documents in a single callback, that won't work. I need to process all documents in some way, existing and incoming, without overloading whatever is executing the migration.  Whether that's a cloud function getting called many times with individual documents, or a Node.js process running on a server.

Comment: Accepted the answer, because it's the only thing that seems to be available. I also may be worrying too much about performance before it's a problem, so we'll solve that when we come to it. Thanks for your time!